# How to find out all the software packages installed by default on a linux install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, package-management, images

I am thinking of getting a VPS and using Ubuntu with it.  I've installed linux on home servers and I almost always choose a very bare system and then install packages manually after the install is complete.

However for a VPS, some providers have pre-made images that can be used.  If I were to use one of them, what is the easiest way of finding out/listing what is already installed, including things like locations and versions?

Answer (score 10):

`dpkg -l` will give you a list of all the applications installed on a debian based box. For more info, check [this page](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/apt-get-intro/info.html.en).

Also, `dpkg -L <pkgname>` shows the files installed for .

Comment: sorry for the late reply. that works great but what about for Red Hat based installs like CentOs?

Comment: @blindcat - just left an answer with the rpm-based answer

Answer (score 2):

Some other useful tricks: if you install "debian-goodies", you'll have the "dpigs" command to display installed package sorted by disk space usage.

Another useful trick if you want to make several similar installations : use

```
dpkg --get-selections > installedpackages.txt
```

On the installed machine then transfer the file to the new machine, and

```
   cat installedpackages.txt | dpkg --set-selections
```

Then do

```
apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

And wait :)

Comment: Useless use of cat detected; you can do just 'dpkg --set-selections < installedpackages.txt' ;)

Comment: Rhaaa I knew it but I was too lazy to check, I just copied and pasted from my notebook :)

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` | ssh othermachine dpkg --set-selections` works, too :)

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS/RHEL/Fedora/etc:

```
rpm -qa | sort
```

Query the `rpm` database for all packages, and put them in alphabetical order :)

Afterwards, I'd rely on using `yum` to manage the packages, rather than `rpm` directly, as it will also handle dependencies.

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo dpkg -l > packageslist
more packageslist
```

Comment: dpkg -l doesn't need superuser access.

Comment: If u have  superuser access it is better to get result